# How can I deploy an ML model from ECS to Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-ecs, amazon-sagemaker

I have a model which was trained locally, then transfered to AWS ECS. I would like to deploy it to Sagemaker.

Currently, I do:

```
from sagemaker.estimator import Estimator
model = Estimator(image,
                  role, 1, 'ml.c4.2xlarge',
                  output_path="s3://{}/output".format(sess.default_bucket()),
                  sagemaker_session=sess)
```

But when I call

```
from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
predictor = agent.deploy(1, 'ml.t2.medium', serializer=csv_serializer)
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-0ca9477e4acb> in <module>()
      1 from sagemaker.predictor import csv_serializer
----> 2 predictor = model.deploy(1, 'ml.t2.medium', serializer=csv_serializer)

~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py in deploy(self, initial_instance_count, instance_type, endpoint_name, **kwargs)
    177         """
    178         if not self.latest_training_job:
--> 179             raise RuntimeError('Estimator has not been fit yet.')
    180         endpoint_name = endpoint_name or self.latest_training_job.name
    181         self.deploy_instance_type = instance_type

RuntimeError: Estimator has not been fit yet.
```

But it has been fit... just not on Sagemaker. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you try to use the SageMaker SDK directly. You need to create a model (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model ) and then create endpoint configuration (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_endpoint_config) and lastly create the endpoint (http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_endpoint )

Comment: Hi I have the same problem. I trained the model locally and want to deploy it on SageMaker. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create [an instance of `Model`](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk#deploying-endpoints-from-model-data) to deploy a model to the endpoint that was not trained in SageMaker:

```
mxnet_model = MXNetModel(model_data="s3://bucket/model.tar.gz", 
                         role="SageMakerRole", 
                         entry_point="trasform_script.py")

predictor = mxnet_model.deploy(instance_type="ml.c4.xlarge", 
                               initial_instance_count=1)
```

The GitHub repo https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples contains more examples on how to deploy models: https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/master/advanced_functionality/tensorflow_iris_byom/tensorflow_BYOM_iris.ipynb and https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/master/advanced_functionality/mxnet_mnist_byom

[sagemaker](/questions/tagged/sagemaker) [amazon-sagemaker](/questions/tagged/amazon-sagemaker) [model](/questions/tagged/model) [inference](/questions/tagged/inference)